# How to Bind http response into ViewModel in C# Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a controller that makes a GET request and returns JSON. I want to then bind those values to the ViewModel that returns to the View.

```
[HTTPGET]
public async Task<IActionResult> Name(string id) {
  ViewModel model = new ViewModel();
  var name = await GetNameFromBYId(id);

  name = model.Name;//HOW Do I do This?

}
```

Comment: `model.Name=name;` is the correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
[HTTPGET]
public async Task<IActionResult> Name(string id) {
  ViewModel model = new ViewModel();
  var name = await GetNameFromBYId(id);

  model.Name = name; // Right code

}
```

This code

> model.Name = name;

only works, if you've created the right Viewmodel before. That means you have defined the right Properties in it. In your example you need to define a "Name" property before in your model, to pass data trough it.

If you have Problems to understand how the MVVM - Pattern works you can search for a simple tutorial like [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level).  Click and read (!), to learn how you make and use ViewModels. Enjoy!